# XAMPP - Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

Tags: php, xampp

When i am trying to start Apache server using XAMPP, it mainly says the following:

```
[Apache]   Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
[Apache]   and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

I checked the error log and it says:

```
"Session Cache is not configured"
```

Complete log is given below:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 5008:tid 316] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5008:tid 316] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5008:tid 316] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[core:notice] [pid 5008:tid 316] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5008:tid 316] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1400
[ssl:warn] [pid 1400:tid 324] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1400:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found a solution:

Here are the instructions how to get rid of the SSLSessionCache message in XAMPP

1) Open file \xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

2) Somewhere in the LoadModule area add the following line:

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

3) Save the file

4) Now open file \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

5) at line 70 add the line

```
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
```

6) Save the file

7) Restart Apache

Comment: Last piece of the puzzle for me - thanks very much (FWIW, I'm using WAMP rather than XAMPP).

Comment: Mine not working I don't know why.  `LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` , `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` and lastly `SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"`. Anything i missed out. The same error shows up all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with you, 
in my case i've installedd sql server 2008 r2.

> you just need to stop the service in service.msc

```
stop all **SQL Service** or maybe one of them
```