# How do I test a website using XAMPP?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

This is a fairly general query as I'm very confused about how to do this. I want to use the apache server which I have downloaded as part of XAMPP in order to test the website I am building, which will use php and mysql. The general question is: how do I do this?

As far as I understand it, the files go into C:\xampp\htdocs, which can then be accessed via localhost. What confuses me though is that the XAMPP admin stuff is also located here - so, for instance, I can't replace the file index.php without losing access to phpMyAdmin and so on. Do I have to create a new folder for the website within this?

I tried setting up a virtual host using instructions I found online. I added it to the windows host file and to the xampp hosts config file as directed [here](http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/), for instance. Having done this the Apache service would not start and gave me an error log very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644064/xampp-session-cache-is-not-configured-hint-sslsessioncache). I followed the instructions given in the answer to that, and it still did not work. I have since removed and reinstalled it and it is working ok again, but without the virtual hosts set up.

Finally, I want to use HTMLPad to build the website because I really like its real time preview feature. However, to set this up, it again needs to be connected with the server. The instructions it gives are:

> In-depth Tutorial: How do I preview PHP files?
>
> To be able to preview PHP files locally without uploading to web, you
>   need to have a web server installed on your computer and it must be
>   configured to support PHP files. Please refer to PHP and web server
>   manuals for more info on installing web server with PHP support.
>
> We recommend to use the free Apache web server from apache.org
>
> Step 1 - What is your document root? Find out what is your local web
>   server document root folder. The document root folder stores web page
>   files available via your web server URL. Please refer to your web
>   server manual for more info.
>
> Step 2 - What is your web server address? Find out what is your local
>   web server URL, usually it is `http://localhost/`
>
> Step 3 - Make sure your web server works Verify that your web server
>   really works with PHP files. To do this, save a PHP file to your web
>   document root and try to open it via web browser. For example, if your
>   web document root is c:\htdocs\, save your file as c:\htdocs\index.php
>   and try to open it via URL `http://localhost/index.php`
>
> If your web server works, you are now ready to configure internal
>   preview.
>
> Step 4 – Configure internal preview Now you must tell the editor
>   software how to use your web server to display the PHP file preview.
>
> On the Options menu, click Preferences; In Preferences window, click
>   Preview folder; Click Mappings, then click Add; Enter your document
>   root folder and the corresponding web address, in the above example
>   you would enter c:\htdocs\ and `http://localhost/`

Again, in the context of all the above, I'm not quite sure I understand this. Presumably this links to all the php, mysql etc files within the original htdocs folder? But does it matter where the files I'm working on are saved, for example?

Basically, I'm just a bit confused, and any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 33):

The webpages on an online server reside in a *location* which looks somewhat like this: `http://www.somerandomsite.com/index.php`

Since xampp is *Offline*, it sets up a local server whose address is like this
`http://localhost/`

Basically, xampp sets up a server (apache and others) in your system. And all the files such as index.php, somethingelse.php, etc., reside in the `xampp\htdocs\` folder.

The browser locates the server in localhost and will search through the above folder for any resources available in there.

So create any number of folders inside the "xampp\htdocs\" each folder thus forming a *website* (as you build it).

Sometimes apache won't even start. This is due to  the clashing of ports with some applications. Some of them I commonly encounter is Skype. See to that it is killed completely and restart apache

Comment: You can just change the port of apache if it conflict with other applications

Comment: Upvote for "xampp\htdocs\"  I just looking for the www which is in wamp. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

Just make a new folder inside C:\xampp\htdocs like C:\xampp\htdocs\test and place your index.php or whatever file in it. Access it by browsing localhost/test/

Good luck!

Comment: Additionally, ensure you've started Apache - I've fallen victim to this before :P

Answer (score 10):

Just edit the httpd-vhost-conf scroll to the bottom and on  the last example/demo for creating a virtual host, remove the hash-tags for DocumentRoot and ServerName. You may have hash-tags just before the `<VirtualHost *.80>` and `</VirtualHost>`

After DocumentRoot, just add the path to your web-docs ... and add your domain-name after ServerNmane

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www"
    ServerName example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Be sure to create the www folder under `htdocs`. You do not have to name the folder www but I did just to be simple about it. Be sure to restart Apache and bang! you can now store files in the newly created directory. To test things out just create a simple `index.html` or `index.php` file and place in the `www` folder, then go to your browser and test it out `localhost/` ... Note: if your server is serving php files over html then remember to add `localhost/index.html` if the html file is the one you choose to use for this test.

Something I should add, in order to still have access to the xampp homepage then you will need to create another VirtualHost. To do this just add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName htdocs.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

underneath the last VirtualHost that you created. Next make the necessary changes to your host file and restart Apache. Now go to your browser and visit htdocs.example.com and your all set.

Comment: I like your answer the best, cause sometimes you work on more than one project. The file described it this answer is located under `xampp/apache/conf/extra`

Answer (score 1):

Make a new folder inside htdocs and access it in browser.[Like this](http://javalearnsimply.weebly.com/php-guide.html) or  [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server). Always start Apache when you start working or check whether it has started (in Control panel of xampp).

Answer (score 1):

create a folder inside htdocs, place your website there, access it via localhost or Internal IP (if you're behind a router)  - check out this video demo [here](http://w3-video.com/Web_Tools/XAMPP/xampp_htdocs_website.html)