# Set up WordPress in a pc running XAMPP and IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to install WordPress on my laptop I've already installed XAMPP and have Apache and MySQL running, I downloaded WordPress and extracted it inside htdocs, my laptop already had IIS installed.

When I go to localhost/WordPress I get 404 -Not found, looking at detailed info of the error the Physical path is set to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WordPress and the label of the chrome tab is "IIS 8.5 detailed Error".

This makes me think that my localhost is set to run with IIS and not with XAMPP.

How can I change my localhost to run with XAMPP htdocs instead of IIS wwwroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is change listen port of XAMMP apache server or IIS... 
I don't have IIS but think the two servers listening port 80...

In XAMMP stop all services and go to config for Apache module and chose httpd.conf.

Then replace `LISTEN 80` (around line 58) to other port you want (eg : `LISTEN 8080`),

and `ServerName localhost:8080`(around line 225) with same listened port...

Now to run WordPress on XAMMP you have to run url `localhost:8080/WordPress`, or replace `8080' to your chosen port...

see [this tuto](https://alexjustesen.com/2018/07/30/how-to-change-your-apache-listen-port-number-in-xampp/) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port) for more information...

Only careful to don't chose any reserved port to avoid conflicts, see [List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for more information...

Or if you run windows, you can use WAMPSERVER who comes with best interface to control Apache virtualhost's.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest WordPress package from the official website and extract the contents into the XAMPP default website directory.
Basically, `XAMPP` sets up a server (apache and others) in your system. And all the files such as index.php, somethingelse.php, etc., reside in the xampp\htdocs\ folder.
You could get more details by checking the below link.
[How do I test a website using XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772198/how-do-i-test-a-website-using-xampp)
Then stop IIS's website using port 80，try it again.
[image]
Have a look at the handy guide for installing WordPress.
https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up your XAMPP(Apache) environment with IIS on Windows**

If you want to run Apache and IIS on your same dev machine.

Keep your IIS config as it is (which is running on `http://localhost/`) and update XAMPP config to run on a different port (like `http://localhost:8080/`)

*Let us see how to implement this case step by step.*

**Recommended stop your XAMPP service before doing this configs**

**STEP 1.** Go to the path where your XAMPP has been installed and open file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

search following keyword: `Listen 80` then change the port `80` to another port number let's say `8080` as shown below:

> `Listen 8080`

also search following keyword: `ServerName localhost:80` and change port `80` to `8080` as shown below:

> `ServerName localhost:8080`

**STEP 2.** Go to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\` and open file `httpd-ssl.conf`.

search for keyword `Listen 443` and change to `Listen 449`

search for keyword `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` and change to `<VirtualHost _default_:449>`

search for `ServerName localhost:443` and change to `ServerName localhost:449`