# Magento black screen locale

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento, xampp

Something really stupid is going on here.
I have several magento projects and they were all fine until now.
I get a blank page on every Magento project;

Also if I want to create a new magento project, on the second installation step, it gives a blank page.

XAMPP is giving me several errors (error_log)

```
[Fri Oct 25 10:05:50 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Oct 25 10:05:52 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 25 10:05:52 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 25 10:05:53 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 25 10:16:03 2013] [notice] child pid 3039 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Fri Oct 25 10:16:04 2013] [notice] child pid 3041 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Fri Oct 25 10:25:57 2013] [notice] child pid 2787 exit signal Bus error (10)
[Fri Oct 25 10:25:58 2013] [notice] child pid 2715 exit signal Bus error (10)
```

I did reinstall XAMPP, but still the same errors.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following :

To get rid of the SSLSessionCache message in XAMPP

1) Open file \xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

2) Somewhere in the LoadModule area add the following line:

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

3) Save the file

4) Now open file \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

5) at line 70 add the line

```
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
```

6) Save the file

7) Restart Apache

Ref : [XAMPP - Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644064/xampp-session-cache-is-not-configured-hint-sslsessioncache)

Comment: httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so into server: cannot create object file image or add library

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had the same problem with Magento and I found that it's since I upgraded Mac OS X to 10.9.

I was using XAMPP 1.7.3 .

To solve that, you need to upgrade XAMPP to 1.8.3.

Everything works fine for me now.