# Apache not working

Tags: apache, xampp

Till today morning Apache was working fine, but when I uninstall the antivirus(Avast), It stopped working. When I start, It is starting fine but local host is not opening.

I have checked error log. It says

```
[Sun Jan 05 23:56:24.587622 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4456:tid 332] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Jan 05 23:56:24.657626 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4456:tid 332] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I have tried some solution found on StackOverflow [XAMPP - Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644064/xampp-session-cache-is-not-configured-hint-sslsessioncache)

But still I do not find a way to get rid of this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you check your port 80?

Comment: @Asraful Haque:  Checked it, PID is: 2256 and State is CLOSE_WAIT. Is there ant problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friends thank you for your support. I got the solution for this problem.

It was due to installation of either "**Avast Antivirus**" or "**CCleaner**".

I removed these and again Apache is running perfectly.

> Hope this will help others too.