# Apache Parent Process Exited abruptly

Tags: php, apache, ssl, caching, xampp

```
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:12.693972 2023] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 3704:tid 680] AH02538: Child: Parent process exited abruptly. Child process is ending
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:14.696271 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3704:tid 680] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:21.659834 2023] [core:warn] [pid 10588:tid 664] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:21.664832 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 10588:tid 664] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:21.731866 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10588:tid 664] AH00455: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.2.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:21.731866 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10588:tid 664] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: May 29 2019 11:22:50
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:21.731866 2023] [core:notice] [pid 10588:tid 664] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:21.738807 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10588:tid 664] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9408
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:22.772445 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 9408:tid 684] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Oct 27 16:37:22.843425 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9408:tid 684] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Anyone know how to handle this error?

I tried this one [session cache is not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644064/xampp-session-cache-is-not-configured-hint-sslsessioncache) but still not working. the same error log occured.

already tried any line code below in httpd-ssl.conf (suggested by AI) :

```
#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
#SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
#SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
#SSLSessionCache "shmcb:${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:D:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
```